# IIS can't get access to database of context

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have some troubles with IIS client. I mean, when I use tests or just connect in my DB in MSSMS everything is fine. But when I open my site I get the error:
provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
** - for secure ofc.
Connection string what I found when I debug code:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;integrated security=false;Initial Catalog=**;User ID=**;Password=**;Connection Timeout=60;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Max Pool Size=1024
```

Maybe someone can help me, idk how I should fix that because that is rly strange bug. I mean... all tests works ( they have same connections string)

Comment: Are you really trying to connect to LocalDB from your webserver? Do you really have sql server installed on the same machine as IIS? Perhaps you could share the error message instead of a just a portion of it?

Comment: LocalDB instances are specific to a user. Your IIS site is likely running under an identity that does not, by default, allow successfully creating or accessing a LocalDB instance (for starters, by default IIS will not load a user profile). It's very unlikely you really want to use a LocalDB instance for a website -- in production, you should use a permanent instance of SQL Server. For testing, you can use a LocalDB instance, but you should use one that's shared from a regular user account (`sqllocaldb share`)

Comment: @SeanLange yep , I'm working on my Local Host machine and that is debugging environment , production working on Azure.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I know what i should use in production . Hm... shared account? What does it mean?